# Creating a search bar in the permanent layout (app.html.eex)

Tags: search, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am having a surprisingly hard time figuring out how to create a search bar within the app.html.eex template in the Phoenix Framework. Since the area does not change no matter where on the website you are I would prefer it simply just use a HTML get request with the search parameter, so something like this:

```
<%= button "Search", to: "/search/^search_parameter", method: "get", class: "btn" %>
```

However I don't know how I can put a variable into the *to:* string. This code does obviously not work but I imagine something like this:

```
<div class="search">
  <%= text_input :search, :query, placeholder: "Type search query here.." %>
  <%= button "Search", to: "/search/^search_query", method: "get", class: "btn" %>
</div>
```

I pretty much have no clue what the best approach is and I am just trying this out. So any solution is welcome really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the URL of the search form based on user input, you will need to use Javascript. However I think the better approach is to just use a normal form and have your search action accept POST parameters instead.

The route should be

```
# web/router.ex

post "/search", SearchController, :index
```

The form should look something like this

```
# web/templates/layout/app.html.eex

<%= form_for @conn, search_path(@conn, :index), [name: :search], fn f -> %>
  <%= text_input f, :query %>
  <%= submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can use the `query` parameter in the controller

```
# web/controllers/search_controller.ex

def index(conn, %{"search" => %{"query" => query}}) do
  results = # do the actual search using `query`
  render conn, "index.html", results: results
end
```

If you like, you can keep your original route and action in order to support both methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is exactly what I wanted. I just had issues doing it myself as i was receiving "search_path" could not be found. The method parameters for index were all wrong when I did it :)